# Use Unicode text with seaborn

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to use Unicode text with Seaborn. (Python 2.7)

I can use Unicode text as a tile with matplotlib.
For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
fp = FontProperties(fname='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/takao-gothic/TakaoGothic.ttf')
text = u'bădărău'
plt.plot([1,2,3,2], label=text)
plt.legend(prop=fp)
```

How to set this kind of font properties to seaborn?
Actually, I want to use Unicode text as annotations in the following example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.heatmap(np.array([[1,2,3]]), annot=np.array([['a', 'b', 'c']]), fmt='')
# want to use ă instead of a
```

If I use `ă`, I get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Batchelder link is good to know, but if you are currently making plots with your own strings, not ones passed into the code, try this. The [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/unicode_demo.html) explains how to use unicode literals in your source code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
import numpy as np

sns.set(font="Meiryo")
sns.heatmap(np.array([[1,2,3]]), annot=np.array([['ë', 'bădărău', 'ê']]),fmt='')
show()
```

Result:

[image]

I picked the font out of the ones installed on my system:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager

font_paths = font_manager.findSystemFonts()
font_objects = font_manager.createFontList(font_paths)
font_names = [f.name for f in font_objects]
print font_names
```

from [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753782/default-fonts-in-seaborn-statistical-data-visualization-in-ipython).