# Seaborn, Matplotlib, plot Chinese error

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

here is my sample data `cities_counter[:10]`

```
[('上海', 285), ('杭州', 225), ('北京', 163), ('广州', 136), ('南京', 130), ('武汉', 124), ('深圳', 88), ('温州', 67), ('苏州', 66), ('宁波', 45)]
```

and I want to make a bar plot with Seaborn and Matplotlib, so here is my code

```
>>> sns.set(style="whitegrid")
>>> sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
>>> sns.barplot(x=[k for k, _ in cities_counter[:10]], y=[v for _, v in cities_counter[:10]])
```

and the result is

[image]

ENV:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.5

How can I plot Chinese character?

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580584) helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is you have to set the seaborn font after all seaborn `set` executions, otherwise the setting font operation doesn't work:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.set(font="SimSun")

data = [('上海', 285), ('杭州', 225), ('北京', 163), ('广州', 136)]
sns.barplot(x=[k for k, _ in data], y=[v for _, v in data])
```

[image: Screenshot diagram]

The above code works for me with `matplotlib==3.1.1` and `seaborn==0.9.0`, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set matplotlib font and then set seaborn.And make sure that font is available in your system.

It works for me.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']
mpl.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['SimHei']
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid",{"font.sans-serif":['simhei', 'Arial']})
```

See more about  [seaborn.set](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html) or [seaborn.set_style](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html).

Also you can check out this [issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1009).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I have downloaded the SimHei.ttf and copied it to the corresponding directory, but it doesn't work.